# How can I include CSRFProvider in my existing site?

Tags: coldfusion, csrf, cfc

\edited: added creation of instance

I want to protect a site against CSRF. But because we're on CF9, I cannot use CSRFGenerateToken(). So I've done a little bit of research and found this: [CSRFProvider](https://github.com/michaelsharman/CsrfProvider).
It's a cfc providing protection against CSRF attacks.
My question is, how can I include it in my site? I want to use the 'hidden-forms' method, which is explained as followed:

// Writes a hidden form field to your view, you must pass an 'intention' which should be unique per form, per application
`#csrf.renderToken(intention="my_unique_form_name")#`

// On form submission, the application must verify the token using the same 'intention'
`validSubmission = csrf.verifyToken(intention="my_unique_form_name", token=form._token);`

I have copied the cfc in the apllications directory and created a form inside test.cfm with a hidden field:

```
<cfset csrf = new CSRFProvider()>
<cfform method="post" action="test2.cfm" name="qwertz">  
 <cfinput name="csrftoken" type="hidden" value="#csrf.renderToken(intention="qwertz")#">  
 <cfinput name="whatever" type="text" > <br/>  
 <cfinput name="Submit" type="submit" value="blah">  </cfform>
```

And in test2.cfm:

```
<cfif validSubmission = csrf.verifyToken(intention="qwertz", token=form._token); >  
<p>valid</P>  
<cfelse>  
<p>nope</P 
</cfif>
```

When I'm trying to open the site, it always tells me:

> The method renderToken was not found in component  [actual_path_to_my_applycation]/CSRFProvider.cfc.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Where are you creating an instance of the CSRF class?  i.e. `csrf = new CSRFProvider();` as per the documentation

Comment: I thougt creating an instance is only necessary for the normal usage (request headers)... So I'm creating it nowhere

Comment: So unless you create a `csrf` variable, how do you expect references to `csrf.verifyToken` and `csrf.renderToken` to work?

Comment: Yeah, that was sort of stupid.... I created it now `<cfset csrf = new CSRFProvider()>` but I'm now getting  `The method renderToken was not found in component [actual_path_to_my_applycation]/CSRFProvider.cfc.`

Comment: If you dump out `csrf` what methods does it have?

Comment: The dump only shows: `component CSRFProvider` and says click to expand/collapse but shows nothing more on clicking...

Comment: There's something obviously wrong with your CFC then; I can expand to see 5 methods

Comment: For what it's worth, David Boyer has a repository on Github that he has created to backport functionality from newer versions of ColdFusion to work on older versions of ColdFusion. He has created a backport of the `CSRFGenerateToken()` function. He talks about it here - [ColdFusion 10 backport: CSRF functions](http://misterdai.yougeezer.co.uk/posts/2012/03/14/coldfusion-10-backport-csrf-functions/).  The Github repo is here - https://github.com/misterdai/cfbackport

Comment: @duncan: I wouldn't know what... I've downloaded it several times now...

Comment: @Miguel-F: thanks for pointing this out! I'll give it a try when I'm back at work on Monday!